# What's the difference between the automorphism and isomorphism of graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

What's the difference between the [automorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_automorphism_problem) and [isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) of graph?

> 1. In graph theory, an isomorphism of graphs $G$ and $H$ is a bijection between the vertex sets of $G$ and $H$, $ f \colon V(G) \to V(H) \,\!$ such that any two vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$ are adjacent in $G$ if and only if $ƒ(u)$ and $ƒ(v)$ are adjacent in $H$.
> 2. In the mathematical field of graph theory, an automorphism of a graph is a form of symmetry in which the graph is mapped onto itself while preserving the edge–vertex connectivity.

Could you give a example to explain the difference of the  automorphism and isomorphism from the graph $G$ to $G$ itself? Since not all the isomorphism from the graph $G$ to $G$ itself is automorphism.

---

I have this question when I read [this post](http://naturalunits.blogspot.com/2012/01/remark-on-symmetry-factors.html), please find the key word `An isomorphism is a bijective structure-preserving map`...and there is a paragraph says that

> The graph representation also bring convenience to counting the number of isomorphisms (the pre-factor). For example, for a graph $g$ with $V$ vertices, $E$ edges from some scalar theory, permutation of vertices is equivalent to relabeling of vertices, hence does not change the graph structure. The same goes to permutation of edges. Therefore, the number of graphs isomorphic to $g$ is $V!⋅E!$.

Maybe the `isomorphism` here does not demand to preserve the vertex-edge realtion, only demand to preserve the structure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By definition, an *automorphism* is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$, while an isomorphism can have different target and domain.

In general (in any category), an automorphism is defined as an isomorphism $f:G \to G$.

Comment: Not all the isomorphism from the graph $G$ to $G$ itself is automorphism. Since automorphism preserving the edge–vertex connectivity.

Comment: @EdenHarder I don't understand what you mean. An isomorphism is structure-preserving as well, so it preservers the edge-vertex connectivity.

Comment: Thanks! I update the question.

Comment: @EdenHarder They key word in the page you're linking to is the word "structure preserving". That means exactly that all the vertex-edge incidences are preserved.

Comment: Thanks! I update the question.

Comment: @EdenHarder Okay, I see your problem. The answer is still the same - an automorphism is just an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$. However, it could be that your source are using different definitions.

Comment: So suppose that I have $UG$, the only difference between a structure-preserving isomorphism and automorphism is that for example, in an isomorphism I label a pair of isomorphic graphs from $1,\dots,6$ and the other with $a,\dots,f$; while in an automorphism I _have to_ label both sets from $1,\dots,6$. Is this picture right?

Comment: @user2820579 I guess that's one way of looking at it - though I wouldn' think too much of labellings.

Comment: (Here's a follow up question asked my a new user, which should be put into the comment) @Fredrik Meyer What other differences exist except for different labels of edges and vertices between two graphs? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 12):

As an example, consider the graphs $G$ and $G'$ on 4 vertices, labelled 1, 2, 3 and 4, where $G$ has edge set $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\}\}$ and $G'$ has edge set $\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\}$. Sketch both of these graphs !

Then the permutation $\alpha = (1, 2, 3, 4)$ (in disjoint cycle notation) is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G'$. Why ? Because, applying $\alpha$ to the vertex labels in the edge set of $G$ we obtain the edge set of $G'$. Check this ! Since an isomorphism from $G$ to $G'$ exists, $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic. However, since their edge sets are different, $G$ and $G'$ are not *equal*.

The permutation $\beta = (1, 2)$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$ itself, that is, an automorphism of $G$, also known as a symmetry of $G$. Check this, as above !

Comment: If you are reading this answer and didn't understand that parantheses notation have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4_4Bqj6EdA
It basically means map 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 and 4 to 1.

Answer (score 5):

An automorphism of a graph $\Gamma$ is an isomorphism from $\Gamma$ to itself.

Comment: Not all the isomorphism from the graph G to G itself is automorphism. Since automorphism preserving the edge–vertex connectivity.

Comment: @EdenHarder, an isomorphism takes and edge of $G$ to an edge of $H$ (read the definition that YOU wrote in the question!). Thus every isomorphism from $G$ to $G$ is an automorphism of $G$. BTW, your 2. is an excerpt from Wikipedia entry [Graph Automorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_automorphism_problem), if you'd have bothered to read the next sentence you would see: "...That is, it is a graph isomorphism from G to itself."

Comment: Thanks! I update the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to visualize , think about the adjacency matrix of the graph. After applying the automorphism, it will look same as previous.

Say, $A$ is the adjacency matrix of graph $G$ and $P$ is an automorphism matrix (permutation matrix). 
Then  $P^{-1}AP = A$; Here $P$ is an automorphism (informally).